# add empty div to image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have an image that I want to share. I only have access to add a class to the img tag so I added the class .share and am trying to use jquery to add the share button script. Right now I can only figure out how to add it after but that does not work since it tries to share the whole page instead of just that image. Here is what I have added:

```
$(".share").after('<div class="share-button"></div>');
```

Is there a way to add this div inside of the .share class? I tried append, appendTo, prepend, prependTo, html, but none of those work.

A full demo is located here: http://codepen.io/bskousen/pen/EdaJr

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you will want to user here is .wrap()

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

```
$("img.share").wrap('<div class="share-button"></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

`img` element cannot have other elements inside it in the DOM.

You can keep the `after()` method, nothing wrong with how you do the button, but you will need to figure out how to pass the actual URL of the image to the social sharing plugin you use.

E.g. implement button click yourself and use `$(this).prev().attr('src')` to get image source and then call your plugin via JS.